# Why are the OpenCL C++ bindings in CUDA 11.6 older than in CUDA 10.1?

Tags: c++, binding, cuda, opencl, cross-language

I'm looking at the OpenCL C++ bindings header distributed with several versions of CUDA, and am noticing that the *newer* CUDA versions have *older* C++ bindings:

| CUDA Version | `cl.hpp` version | `cl.hpp` modification year |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 10.1 | 1.2.7 | 2015 |
| 11.2 | 1.2.7 | 2015 |
| 11.4 | 1.2.5 | 2013 |
| 11.6 | 1.2.5 | 2013 |

Why were the C++ bindings downgraded?

And why don't these versions all use the last (AFAICT) version of the C++ bindings header as released by the Khronos consortium, [version 1.2.8](https://github.com/KhronosGroup/OpenCL-Registry/blob/main/api/2.1/cl.hpp) from October 2015?

Note: The differences are not at all trivial: `diff -uwB` followed by `diffstat` tells us 1179 insertions, 691 deletions.

Comment: Have you checked the file contents with something like DiffChecker? I think the files are all identical.

Comment: @ProjectPhysX: There are lots and lots of changes; see edit.